# Wrap SQL CONTAINS as an expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a question. I working on one site on Asp.Net, which uses some ORM. I need to use a couple of FullTextSearch functions, such as Contains. But when I try to generate it with that ORM, it generates such SQL code

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name] 
    FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (Contains([Extent1].[Name], N'qq')) = 1
```

SQL can't parse it, because Contains doesn't return bit value. And unfortunately I can't modify SQL query generation process, but I can modify statements in it.

My question is - is it possible to wrap call of CONTAINS function to something else? I tried to create another function, that will SELECT with contains, but it requires specific table\column objects, and I don't want to do one function for each table..

**EDIT**

I can modify result type for that function in ORM. In previous sample result type is Bit. I can change it to int,nvarchar,etc. But as I understood there is no Boolean type in SQL, and I can't specify it.

Comment: Can't you put this in a stored procedure, and tell your ORM to call the stored procedure? Why does every ORM-related question make it seem like ORM is taking database technology ten years into the past?

Comment: Can it be used within `IIF` or `CASE`?

Comment: Yes, I can, but in this way, I should put every SQL with contains into new stored procedure. If it possible, I want to make more generic way, which can handle it without specific table.

Comment: @pst, I can use IIF, but the check still be invalid. For IIF it will generate such sql - WHERE IIF(Contains([Extent1].[Name], N'qq') == 1, firstRes, secondRes)

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Around the CONTAINS sans equality operator returning 1 or 0: `(iff(contains(...),1,0)) = 1`

Comment: ORM is building some kind of Expression trees, and Contains is one of the nodes in that tree. And checking for result type is also part of that tree, which I can't modify. And it will generate Contains(..) == 1. Unfortunately I can't move that check forward or behind...

Comment: Time to find a new tool or modify the existing one? ;-)

Comment: I'm afraid this decision :) But if there is no any other variants, than i prefer stored procedure. It's not so flexible, but it will works :)

Comment: How does the ORM handle EXISTS?  Could you get the ORM to do something similar with CONTAINS?

Comment: I am yet to see an ORM tool that actually works. What I mean is that it is flexible to support, and easy enough to make changes without having to recompile and deploy the whole project. In my eyes stored procedures are the way to go, and if you have to, write your own ORM with scaffolding. This way you stay in control, at all levels.

Comment: I think, that it fully depends on specific project. ORM gives us better development speed for typical cases, and it can be awful for non typical cases.

Comment: I hesitate to suggest this, but perhaps SQL CLR could be used to build such a mapping, wrapping the Contains and returning a bool.  What you'd end up with.. probably wouldn't be much worse than the rest of the ORM solution...

Comment: SQL CLR could be a solution, but in my case, I rewrited it as a couple of stored procedure. These SPs loads data from specific tables. And I call them from C# and that ORM. It's not a good way, because we use ORM everywhere, but it was one of the simplest ways and time was running out. I tried to extend that ORM, but it still generates incorrect SQL query.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov: I'm with Ryk.  ORMs make life easy for about 80% of your queries, which are the simply CRUD ones.  Once you start going beyond that (which most applications do) then they are a boat anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you put this in a stored procedure, and tell your ORM to call the stored procedure? Then you don't have to worry about the fact that your ORM only understands a subset of valid T-SQL.

I don't know that I believe the argument that requiring new stored procedures is a blocker. If you have to write a new CONTAINS expression in your ORM code, how much different is it to wrap that expression in a CREATE PROCEDURE statement in a different window? If you want to do this purely in ORM, then you're going to have to put pressure on the vendor to pick up the pace and start getting more complete coverage of the language they should fully support.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I did via a couple of stored proc. This way isn't so clear, but it works ok.